# How to fix the height and the width of wpf windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on wpf application and i want to fix the heigth and the width of the windows . I'm using Metro style so i can't use the proprity of FormBorderStyle . 
I tried to use MaxWidth and MaxHeigth ( MinWidth and MinHeigth ) it works but when i excute the code a black border appears

here's the code

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Selen.Wpf.DemoApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Title="A propos "
    MaxHeight="400" MaxWidth="550" MinHeight="400" MinWidth="550" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" TitleForeground="#999988" Background="Black" 
    WindowStyle="None"  ShowMaxRestoreButton="False" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"  >


<Grid Background="#FF2D2D30" >
    <TabControl Width="653">
        <TabItem Header="Projet">
            <Grid Background="#FF2D2D30" Margin="0,0,-7,0">
                <TextBlock x:Name="text" Foreground="Green" TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="16" Text="Modélidation d'une surface Topographique en 2D et 3D" Margin="10,10,204,0" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="446" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="text1" Foreground="White" FontSize="14" Margin="6,75,0,196" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Le domaine de Sig a connu une grande  developpement , &#xa; maintenant il est utilisé dans le domaine &#xa; de topographie pour définir les différentes surfaces &#xa; et isovaleurs contant dans  une surface terrstre" Width="407" />
                <Image x:Name="im" Margin="360,38,129,145" Source="Images/photo.jpg" Grid.Column="0" Height="184" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="171"/>
                <Button Width="100" Height="30" Content="Suivant" Margin="410,258,150,79" Click="button1_click" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Equipe"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Outils"></TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

Comment: What means "fix" in your context? Non-resizable?

Comment: Have you tried setting `ResizeMode="NoResize"` in the window definition?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
<Window ResizeMode="NoResize" Height="450" Width="650">
</Window>
```

Comment: This also remove window minimize button!

Comment: @Mohammad what version of .NET you experienced that?

Comment: @SebastianXaweryWiśniowiecki I just tried this in a WPF (.NET Core 3.1) project and it worked

Comment: also, those who need a non-resizable but minimisable window, `ResizeMode="CanMinimize"` does the trick